# Problems doing Travis-CI builds with new Flutter project

Tags: flutter, travis-ci, flutter-test

I have started working on a new Flutter project and I was trying to get Travis-CI integrated with this project. I previously had successfully configured Travis-CI for another Flutter project and it worked perfectly. However this time around it doesn't seem to be working. The builds are not getting triggered at all, not sure where the problem lies. Has someone faced a similar issue? What will be the best course of action? Should I contact Travis support or is there a config issue that I am not seeing, similar configs work for the other project. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Github: https://github.com/sudhanshu-15/sunapsisConference2018Flutter

Travis: https://travis-ci.com/sudhanshu-15/sunapsisConference2018Flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an error with my `.travis.yml` file. I copied the configurations from the other project and it messed it up. It added a whitespace which was messing up with the configurations.

**Lessons learned:**

- Do not copy and paste content from `.travis.yml`
- Do yourself a favor and validate your `.travis.yml` with http://www.yamllint.com - it will definitely help you find some issues.
- Better approach than using the yamllint is to install `travis gem`, more info available here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#lint - This will list out all possible errors in your configuration file.

Hope this helps someone who faced a similar issue. 
Thanks to everyone who looked at this issue.